# Override document.title, then use original method

Tags: javascript

The problem is that I have a component(which is not my code, so I can't change it) that calls document.title="". Of course I won't allow that, so my plan is to override the document.title method and check for an empty string. But how do I handle a call that sets the document.title = Correct Title, with the overriden method.

Here is my code so far:

```
var actualTitle = document.title;

Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
    set: function (newValue) {
        if(newValue != ""){
            document.title = newValue;
        }
    },

    get: function () {
        return actualTitle;
    }
});
```

This code makes an infinite loop, because the method calls it self. But I need to actually set the title inside the set method.

Is there some sort of super method I can use, like you can in for example Java.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have override methods like Java, you'll just reset the function. `document.title` isn't a function though, it's a property of the document object.

Comment: It doesn't work, even if you managed to remove the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
    set: function (newValue) {
        if(newValue != ""){
            document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = newValue;
        }
    },

    get: function () {
        return document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    }
});
```

How it works:

When I use `Object.defineProperty`, the page's title won't change when you use `document.title = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"`. So, let's hack it.

We still have another way to change the title: `document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML`. So, let's change the value of `document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML` every time the value of `document.title` is changed. But you hate `document.title = ""` so let's ignore this by `if(newValue != "")`

Answer (score 1):

You can stop modification of the title simply by making the property non-writable (which is the default), and giving it the value you'd like:

```js
function lockDocumentTitle() {

  // extract the initial value
  var actualTitle = document.title;

  // override the property to always have that value
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
    value: actualTitle,
    /* 
    By default:
      - not enumerable
      - not configurable
      - not writable
    */
  });
}

console.log(document.title);             // ''
document.title = 'Test';     
console.log('Set to ' + document.title); // 'Test'

lockDocumentTitle();

document.title = 'Something Else';       // no effect
console.log('Still ' + document.title);  // its still 'Test'
```

Comment: If you look at my example, it shows you that once you lock the title, it can't be changed. I see now that you still want to allow changes, only not to the empty string.

Comment: This works. But in my project, I can't lock the title, because the code is async and I can't be sure of the order they are called. So  @LearnHowToBeTransparent answer works best for my use.

Comment: i just want to tell you that `Object.defineProperty` trick to make the variable not writable won't work for objects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @LearnHowToBeTransparent?

Comment: @gautedevelopment if the code is async, how do you know when to define the getter/setter then? It has the same problem - you could define it *after* the title is already changed to `""`. If you only want the title of your page to be what you defined in the html, run `lockDocumentTitle` before the problematic script (or maybe before all scripts) and it will work. In the same way, you must run the code suggested by LearnHowToBeTransparent **before** the problematic script to ensure it works as intended.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent I see now what you mean, good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Will a simple flag do?

```
var actualTitle = document.title,
    isModified = false;

Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
    set: function (newValue) {
        isModified = true;
        if(newValue != "" && !isModified){
            document.title = newValue;
        }
    },

    get: function () {
        return actualTitle;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will stop the infinite loop, but it will not actually change the title of the web page. It will just run the method twice.