How to console.log every time document.title is set?
I'm debugging some messy code base and I'm trying to figure out where document.title is being set (there are too many places and libraries calling document.title = foo).
My plan is to override the setter of that property and add a console.log/console.trace to see where it's coming from.
How can I override the set of document.title?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044790/1427878
